# PHP Datatable SearchPaneOptions Order By Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I'm using bootstrap's server side processing on a table to bring data. I'm also using the "searchPaneOptions" to create  filters on some of the columns.

I have this data saved on column **price** in my database

```
1-1
100-249
1k+
2-50
250-299
300-999
51-99
```

What I want is for that filter look like:

```
1-1
2-50
51-99
100-249
250-299
300-999
1k+
```

There is the part of my code which I inflate this specific column:

As you guys could see there is a **order** option there, but apparently its ignored.

```
->field(Field::inst( 'price' )
    ->searchPaneOptions( searchPaneOptions::inst()
        ->table( 'report' )
        ->value( 'price' )
        ->label( 'price' )
        ->order( 'price ' )
    )
)
```

Here is the documentation that I'm following:
https://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/searchpanes

Any ideas to help me?